# Changing an image location in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

I am trying to have the location of an image change when I mouseover. I have:

```
<Image 
    Name="cat" 
    Source="CatRun.bmp" 
    Visibility="Hidden" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Width="100" 
    Height="100"
    UIElement.MouseEnter="cat_MouseEnter"/>
```

in XAML and:

```
private void cat_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

in C#.

How can I set the location specifically on the canvas?

Comment: var image = (Image)sender;
    Canvas.SetLeft(image, 42);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Fill="Blue" MouseEnter="RectangleMouseEnter" />
</Canvas>
```

You need to set the attached properties top, left (or bottom, right)

```
    private void RectangleMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, 50);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 50);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to set position of the Image on the Canvas from code-behind you can use something like:

```
private void cat_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(cat, 100); //set x coordinate of cat Image to 100
    Canvas.SetTop(cat, 300); //set y coordinate of cat Image to 300
}
```

**Update:**
In some cases you may not be able to access `cat` object by name from that method. In order to make it work, just use the sender object that should be the `Image` that caused the event, as H.B. described in his comment.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it won't compile then. I'll update the answer with some more info.